# storing n amount of integers n <15 from a file into array

Tags: c++, arrays, pseudocode

I am learning file stream and arrays and wanted to practice. I am also practicing writing pseudo code.I wrote the pseudo code for this program that stores numbers from file into integer array.Everything seems easy to implement into code except one part. I don't know how the increment would work. Any help or feedback would be much appreciated.

Here is what's in the file. Only numbers in the line that starts with Test1 will be stored in the array.

```
Test1 words to ignore: 14 26 45 48 65 26 49
Dummy line: 15 17 45
Test1 words I want to ignore2: 14 15 22 
Test1 dont read this words: 11 15
```

Edit : I acutally wrote the code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include <string>


const int ARRAY_SIZE = 15;
void fucn(std::ifstream &);


int main()
{
    std::ifstream myFile("test.txt");
    fucn(myFile);
    myFile.close();
}
void fucn(std::ifstream & myFile)
{
    int myArray[ARRAY_SIZE] = {0};

    int i =0;
    std::string strName;
    while (!(myFile>>strName).eof())
    {
        myFile.ignore(INT_MAX,':');
       if (strName == "Test1")
       {
           while (myFile >>myArray[i])  //This part is not reading anything.
           {
               ++i;
           }
       }


    }
    for (int myVar: myArray)
    {
        std::cout <<myVar <<" ";
    }
}
```

Comment: "Incrementing the counter" is as simple as adding `1` to your counter variable.

Comment: "increment" == "increase by one"

Comment: @BessieTheCow I am aware that incrementing means increase by one. What I wanted to know was if it should be placed in inner loop since incrementing it would only take 1 input from the line, I want to grab all the numbers from the line.

Comment: It stores the current position in the array, so you would increment it every time you read a number.